# Get element from a table

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I have the following table:

```
\begin{filecontents}{table.dat}
a   0.70
b   0.58
\end{filecontents}
```

and I am trying to access at the elements with the command `\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\table` but I obtain only the following error:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column '0' from
>   table 'table.dat'. Please check spelling (or introduce name
>   aliases)..

I know that the problem is with the letter, because the error disappear if in the table there are only numerical values.

Comment: use `header=false` when reading the table. Otherwise we have to see how you coded .

Comment: @percusse You should write an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have headers, then you should dispatch that during the table reading. Then you can use the `[index]` notation for unnamed columns. Otherwise, the parser thinks that there is a column named `0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
a   0.70
b   0.58
}\mytable
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\mytable
\pgfplotsretval
\end{document}
```

gives `a` as the result.